# Get information of tf/tf2 by code

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi you guys,

I'm quite new to ROS. I'm making a fake robot in Gazebo and I'm done with creating the model.

After execute "rostopic list", I saw /tf. And "rostopic echo -n 1 /tf" returns some information about position and orientation like in [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MiuAa9Kn07tJkge6Jn1aD1gUW_98Dsqp/view?usp=sharing).

How can I get that information of a specific link by code, not all link at the same time?

How can I publish the new pose of a specific link by code and display it in Gazebo?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384742/get-information-of-tf/tf2-by-code/) by [Irobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/81777/irobo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Irobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/81777/irobo/) on 2021-08-20**:
Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see whether the [TF2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) can help you get an understanding of what's going on.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1